# Error en función en MySql

Tags: mysql

escribo porque deseo que me den una ayuda o idea para encontrar la solución

Tengo la siguiente función en mysql desde workbench:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS IntHoraria;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION IntHoraria(CfGrMa_anoLectivoPA VARCHAR(4), CfGrMa_GradIdPA INT, CfGrMa_MateIdPA INT) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE Area INT;
    DECLARE MateAreas VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE IntensidadHoraria INT;
    
    SET Area = (SELECT MateAreaId FROM materias WHERE MateId= CfGrMa_MateIdPA);
    
    SET MateAreas = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( MateId SEPARATOR ', ') FROM materias wHERE MateAreaId = Area);
    
   SET IntensidadHoraria = (SELECT SUM(CfGrMa_IntensidadHoras)
                            FROM configradmat
                            INNER JOIN materias ON CfGrMa_MateId=MateId 
                            WHERE CfGrMa_anoLectivo = CfGrMa_anoLectivoPA AND CfGrMa_GradId = CfGrMa_GradIdPA 
                            AND CfGrMa_MateId IN (MateAreas));
   
    RETURN IntensidadHoraria;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

La función la llamo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT IntHoraria('2020', 2, 13) AS NoHoras;
```

Y estos son los valores que toman las variables asignadas en la función, en el ejemplo que estoy desarrollando:

Área = 3
MateÁreas = 1,13,16

Al llamar la función me arroja el siguiente error:

> Código de error: 1292. Valor DOBLE incorrecto truncado: '1, 13, 16'

Espero me puedan ayudar para encontrar una solución y detectar en que consiste el error, para tenerlo en cuenta.

De antemano muchas gracias por su valiosa colaboración.

---

Buen día, gracias por contestar, si ya lo intente como dices.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS IntHoraria;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION IntHoraria(CfGrMa_anoLectivoPA VARCHAR(4), CfGrMa_GradIdPA INT, CfGrMa_MateIdPA INT) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE Area INT;
    DECLARE MateAreas VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE IntensidadHoraria INT;
    
    SET Area = (SELECT MateAreaId FROM materias WHERE MateId= CfGrMa_MateIdPA);
    
   -- SET MateAreas = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( MateId SEPARATOR ', ') FROM materias wHERE MateAreaId = Area);
    
   SET IntensidadHoraria = (SELECT SUM(CfGrMa_IntensidadHoras)
                            FROM configradmat
                            INNER JOIN materias ON CfGrMa_MateId=MateId 
                            WHERE CfGrMa_anoLectivo = CfGrMa_anoLectivoPA AND CfGrMa_GradId = CfGrMa_GradIdPA 
                            AND CfGrMa_MateId IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( MateId SEPARATOR ', ') FROM materias wHERE MateAreaId = Area));
   
    RETURN IntensidadHoraria;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Y el resultado no es el esperado por que me arroja como resultado 1

Si lo hago de esta manera, el resultado es el correcto 5

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS IntHoraria;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION IntHoraria(CfGrMa_anoLectivoPA VARCHAR(4), CfGrMa_GradIdPA INT, CfGrMa_MateIdPA INT) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE Area INT;
    DECLARE MateAreas VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE IntensidadHoraria INT;
    
    SET Area = (SELECT MateAreaId FROM materias WHERE MateId= CfGrMa_MateIdPA);
      
   SET IntensidadHoraria = (SELECT SUM(CfGrMa_IntensidadHoras)
                            FROM configradmat
                            INNER JOIN materias ON CfGrMa_MateId=MateId 
                            WHERE CfGrMa_anoLectivo = CfGrMa_anoLectivoPA AND CfGrMa_GradId = CfGrMa_GradIdPA 
                            AND CfGrMa_MateId IN (1, 13, 16));
   
    RETURN IntensidadHoraria;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

No se a que se debe que si lo hago con la consulta, no arroja el valore real que debe arrojar, que es 5

Veo que al aplicar esta sentencia:

```
DECLARE MateAreas VARCHAR(20);

SET MateAreas = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( MateId SEPARATOR ', ') FROM materias wHERE MateAreaId = Area);
```

Pienso que la variable MateAreas, debería ser como una lista, no se si este equivocado

Comment: Estás estableciendo como un entero la salida, ¿seguro que un entero te es retornado?

Comment: en tu ejemplo `Área = 3 MateÁreas = 1,13,16`cual seria la supuesta salida de la funcion?

Comment: Llamo a la función con estos parámetros **SELECT IntHoraria('2020', 2, 13) AS NoHoras;**, donde envío como parámetro el año, grado y la materia. Con lo cual se selecciona el área al cual pertenece esa materia, **Area = 3**, y las materias que pertenecen a esa área y **MateÁreas  = 1,13,16**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día, comparto la solución, para alguien más en un futuro y doy por cerrada la pregunta.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS IntHoraria;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION IntHoraria(CfGrMa_anoLectivoPA VARCHAR(4), CfGrMa_GradIdPA INT, CfGrMa_MateIdPA INT) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE Area INT;
    DECLARE MateAreas nvarchar(20); 
    DECLARE IntensidadHoraria INT;
    
    SET Area = (SELECT MateAreaId FROM materias WHERE MateId= CfGrMa_MateIdPA);              
    
   SET IntensidadHoraria = (SELECT SUM(CfGrMa_IntensidadHoras)
                            FROM configradmat
                            INNER JOIN materias ON CfGrMa_MateId=MateId 
                            WHERE CfGrMa_anoLectivo = CfGrMa_anoLectivoPA AND CfGrMa_GradId = CfGrMa_GradIdPA 
                            AND CfGrMa_MateId IN (SELECT concat_ws(' ',  MateId ) FROM materias wHERE MateAreaId = Area));
   
    RETURN IntensidadHoraria;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Y lo llamo de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT IntHoraria('2020', 2, 8) AS NoHoras;
```

Gracias a todos por su valiosa colaboración.

Comment: No sabía que mysql tenía posibilidad de usar nvarchar, por cierto no olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Como lo hago, no veo esa opción, gracias. Ya lo encontré, pero me dice que lo puedo hacer es mañana.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente sea por la concatenación que haces de `MateAreas` pues es un `VARCHAR`, y después lo utilizas en el `IN`, quedando la consulta como `SELECT SUM(...) FROM ... IN ("1, 2, 3")` lo cual no hace sentido. Debería ser `SELECT SUM(...) FROM ... IN (1, 2, 3)`.

Si ese es el caso, haz el query ahí mismo en el `IN`, de forma tal que el query quede como

```
SELECT ... IN (SELECT MateId FROM materias WHERE MateAreaId = Area)
```

Y entonces sí se evalúe la consulta correctamente como `SELECT SUM(...) FROM ... IN (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Buen día, gracias por contestar, si ya lo intente como dices. 

Debe dar **5** y da como resultado **1**

    set = select ... AND CfGrMa_MateId IN (1, 13, 16));          

Veo que al aplicar esta sentencia:

    DECLARE MateAreas VARCHAR(20);
    
    SET MateAreas = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( MateId SEPARATOR ', ') FROM materias wHERE MateAreaId = Area);

Pienso que la variable **MateAreas**, debería ser como una lista, no se si este equivocado

Comment: Gracias **padaleiana**, por la aclaración, ya elimine el mensaje y lo deje como un comentario.